# Are questions asking for documentation off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I came across two questions asking for a link or another way to access the documentation of a library. I immediately thought it has to be off-topic, but the close-reason doesn't state documentation:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Is asking for documentation off-topic? If it is, how can I justify flagging it? (The close reason doesn't fit IMO)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The close reason does fit. Documentation is an *off-site resource*, and that is specifically defined as off-topic.

Comment: I don't get it. `off-site resource ... tend to attract opinionated answers and spam`. How is asking for the official documentation page can attract opinionated answers and spam? does a product have more than one official doc?

Comment: Not just that. SO doesn't want to become a link database with just dead links. That will happen for sure (consider Microsofts move to docs.microsoft.com, Sun/Oracle breaking their Java docs, etc.)

Comment: It still can help lots of people for a considerable amount of time. *In any case*, asking for the official documentation IMO is more important and useful than many of the open questions which are basically spam. Maybe, we shouldn't erase the question itself, but find a workaround for the downsides.

Comment: This might be too broad. I just asked a question along the lines of 'is this documented behavior or a bug' after searching the docs and failing to find an answer, and someone shot down the question with a link to this meta discussion and the brilliant comment 'I don't see how asking people to read/search the docs for you is a suitable question for SO'...    
Asking for a recommendation on any tool, library, book or any off-site resource indeed calls for opinions. Excluding all documentation as off-site resources - is going too far. (docs is pretty much all we have).

Comment: This advice is outdated. [A former CM weighed in on why this is *not* closable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/386006/2370483)