# Why is this question marked off-topic

Tags: discussion, scope

[Where can I find the source for "fetch" implementation used in Chromium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59717147/where-can-i-find-the-source-for-fetch-implementation-used-in-chromium?noredirect=1#comment105585982_59717147)

It is not asking for recommendation as noted in the closing dialog.

It can be asking for help with the external tool (Chromium), but then all questions about Chromium are off-topic and there are 2.7k of them and there is evena Chromium tag.

Comment: You look to be asking for an off-site resource as per the comment to your question. And not all chromium questions are asking for off-site resources; most are asking about problems with the original poster's code.

Comment: *"It is not asking for recommendation as noted in the closing dialog."* how is it not asking for an off-site resource? *"Where can I find the exact source file(s) for "fetch" implementation used in Chromium?"* What other interpretation of "Where can I find" is there?

Comment: Yeah, those close votes are pretty nonsensical if taken literally.  You can possibly rescue it by asking *how* to find it instead of where to find it.  Somebody might be able to post a guide to the codebase without having to write a book about it.

Comment: First of all why did I get 8 downvotes on this specific meta question without any comment about why is it downvoted?

Comment: @gnat It did not. My question is definitely not a "recommendation" question.

Comment: @LarnuIt Maybe it is "asking for an off-site resorce". You quoted me and I said in that quote "I'm not asking for RECOMMENDATION..." not "I'm not asking for an off-site resource".

Comment: @MichaelGaskill After I read that I still don't understand if my question is offtopic or not. ChrisF says every resource request is offtopic. And per those answers I think mine is not. In general wherever I check it says something like: "The general rule against off-site resources is targeted at this type of question
'Does anyone know of a library to do this thing?' " My question is not opinionated.

Answer (score 22):

The question is asking to find the source code.

That's a resource request and as such is definitely off topic.

Comment: Thanks CrhisF. I see you are an admin. Can you expain me why I got 8 downvotes on this specific META question (noone said why it downvoted in the comment)

Comment: @croraf: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254108/downvotes-on-meta-are-confusing-do-they-really-mean-poor-post-quality-or-jus

Comment: @croraf If people don't explain why they downvote I can only speculate and I'm reluctant to do that.

Comment: But not one from the downvoters explained why they downvoted...

Comment: @ChrisF This says in the off-topic reason on my question: "We don’t allow questions seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more. Edit the question so it can be answered with facts and citations." Is it my question asking for a recommendation or cannot be answered with facts and citations? I think my question is completely the opposite of that reason. (although it might be offtopic still, as you say)

Comment: @croraf - you're explicitly looking for an offsite resource. The "and more" covers your case.

Comment: OK, I know that and more can mean any external resource. But I'm not asking for a RECOMMENDATION which is a key word in this note. But OK. I reformatted my original question.

Comment: @ChrisF https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385479/when-is-a-resource-request-on-topic So the answer to this is: never?

Comment: @croraf - correct. The answer is "never".

Answer (score 6):

Even if your question is not asking us to do the heavy lifting for you, how useful will that question be for future visitors?

A couple of minutes googling brings you to [/blink/renderer/core/fetch/](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/third_party/+/master/blink/renderer/core/fetch/) which has an readme.md that states:

> The implementation of the [Fetch API](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#fetch-api).
>
> Fetching/loading code is divided into:
>
> core/fetch: Fetch API
>   core/loader: high-level fetching
>   platform/loader/fetch: low-level fetching

In  your question you say:

> More specifically I want to find the implementation of response.json() function returned from fetch response.

Why? What is the practical problem you're facing that makes that you're interested in the implementation of that function? What issue have you fixed once you looked at that C++ code? How can your challenge turn up as a hurdle for others as well?

Or is it just for curiosity? Then you can still formulate an interesting thought about it. Maybe its garbage collection strategy, its buffer reuse, its error handling. Something else that is both interesting and applicable to the day to day operation of being a developer working with that fetch api.

Without all that context you simply deferred the googling to someone else. Congrats. You have your answer. I've done that bit for you. None of that answer nor your question is interesting for future visitors. And that still is, until further notice, the goal for content on Stack Overflow.

Comment: OK, I can be more specific. And I can reformulate not to directly ask for the external resource. But my offtopic is for sure not in line with the maked reason stating: "We don’t allow questions seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more. Edit the question so it can be answered with facts and citations." And indeed I ask a citation of the source directly. So the suggestion to the offtopic says that the answer should have citations (which are external resources), while in my question I must not ask for citations (because that is asking for external resource).

Comment: @croraf that "citation" would need several files then because by the looks of it there is an IDL as well as several .h and .cc files. I fail to see how that citation is useful, nor how having the link to it is.

Comment: Ideal answer to my question would have link to the source folder, and refering to the specific files from that folder with short explanation what each file is for. In my opinion this would be useful in the future for anyone who should search for anything regarding low level details of "fetch". You think this is too wide granularity, I disagree. Anyway, this is not the thing at all, the thing is SO doesn't allow for explicit asking for the reference but any good answer should be backed by references (so I see this rule being kinda insane).

Comment: @croraf there are 65 files in that folder. Do you really expect someone to summarize those in an answer? Srsly? That is way too broad.

Comment: I didn't know there are 65 files before posting the question. And when you see there are test, h and cc files grouped, there are 15 concepts in total. Not every one needs to be explained, so I think it is manageable.

Comment: "Ideal answer to my question would have link to the source folder," - how that is not a request for "or other off-site resources"? The post was not asking for any explanation that can "be backed by references", it was just asking for the link (which indeed can go stale and thus not welcome as answer on SO).