# Are questions about the Power Apps platform itself acceptable here?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, closed-questions

I asked a question earlier this year that got closed because it needed "to be more focused". While I thought that the question was focused enough, I tried to edit it and voted for it to be reopened, only to see it being automatically deleted after some inactivity (or that is what I could understand from it).

This is the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59542600/what-are-the-limitations-of-the-restore-command-in-powerapps-version-history

I got curious about why the question was closed/deleted. It is a simple question about a low-code development platform that there is no code involved, it is not about a specific app or formula.

Maybe it was just skipped by a lot of people in the reopen queue?
Or maybe it is really still too broad? 
Or maybe it is a kind of question that is not welcome here?

So, before asking similar questions in the future, i decided to ask here (according to the help center, this is the place to ask that - https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions).

---

Edit: I just noticed that as the question was deleted it might be difficult for most people to see it. in summary, the question was: "What are the limitations of the restore option?"

Comment: To answer why your question was deleted, it was deleted by Roomba: [The Community user deleted my question! What gives?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba)

Comment: I dunno, but the [tag:powerapps] wiki is clearly plagiarised from [here](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/hr-hr/blog/introducing-microsoft-flow-and-announcing-the-public-preview-of-powerapps/)

Comment: As for your question, from reading it appears to ask for a 3rd party article, specifically documentation, which is off-topic for SO.

Comment: Thanks, Larnu, for both comments. I was trying to ask for information regarding the restore option, though of course a documentation about it would be great.

Comment: @Larnu I think this question is not off-topic for asking for a software request, as per the [answer to When is a resource request on-topic? by Shog](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/386006/7296893). The problem is quite specific. I think it's off-topic because it's not directly related to programming, though

Answer (score 2):

Only when they are directly related to programming.

Questions regarding issues like licensing and administration for PowerApps are off-topic.

Yours is on an edge-case, but in my opinion closer to off-topic than on-topic. It's probably best asked on an official support forum.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense regarding where to draw a line. So, in that case, should the question have been closed as being off-topic instead of being "too broad"?

Comment: Since we don't have a specific _Off-topic_ -> _Not programming related_ reason, people often pick another reason semi-randomly instead of taking the effort to write up a reason. I think _Off-topic_ would fit a lot better than _Too broad_, since it's a very specific question, but we generally don't re-open questions just to close them again for another reason