# What tag *should* be used to ask for documentation?

Tags: discussion, tags

From the [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/documentation) description:

> THIS TAG IS FOR DOCUMENT GENERATORS ONLY. Include language and/or SDE tag as well. DO NOT USE to ask for links to documentation or tools, or to critique vendor documentation.

But that bring up the question of what to do when you *are* asking  for links to documentation.

- If it's worth calling that out as off-topic and there is a *correct* tag (or isn't a general one at all) for that, then should the `documentation` tag mention the correct thing to do?
- Or is that saying that asking after documentation is specifically OT for SO (more than the  standard "do your due diligence")?

FWIW: [context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60709754/documentation-for-3rd-party-use-of-googles-userfeedback-widget)

Comment: IIRC asking for the location of a specific piece of documentation for something specific to programming is allowed, one of Shog's rules I think ([source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385479/when-is-a-resource-request-on-topic))

Comment: FYI "OT" is a successful abbreviation for both "on topic" and "off topic" ;).

Comment: You wonder what [tag:documentation-generation] is for then..., since `documentation-generator` is a synonym of that, and not of `documentation`.

Comment: In general, asking us to ["recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are" explicitly off-topic on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). However, there's [debate as to if asking where to find *official* sources](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385479/when-is-a-resource-request-on-topic) is on-topic.

Comment: Maybe there should be a an `official-documentation` tag?

Comment: I've yet to see non-off-topic request for documentation outside of language specifications... For later "language-lawyer" is an option...

Comment: @BCS No, that’s a “meta” tag in that it does not describe the content of the question. Tag the question with what technologies you’re asking about. And rather than asking for someone to locate documentation specifically, ask about the problem you are having. Let the *answerer* decide whether it’s appropriate to share documentation.

Comment: @CodyGray: in the prompting case, I actually am looking for the official docs. That is "the problem [I'm] are having". I need to do something the officially supported way. If an answer doesn't cite those docs, then I must not trust it. If it cites the docs, then it need do nothing more.

Comment: “My question, then, is: what is the official way to solve this problem using technology *x*?”

Comment: @CodyGray I consider your stance to be wrong. We are just going to have to disagree.

Comment: Heh. Well, I’m giving you a workaround that allows you to ask the question on Stack Overflow. The fact is that “locate a resource” questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow, so we’re not only not going to be creating a tag for them, but they’re highly likely to get closed. Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, not a locator/recommendation engine.

Answer (score 6):

At first glance, you'd think a request for a link to official documentation would be reasonable and not off-topic for Stack Overflow...

Problem is, from the site's perspective, the link to documentation may change. (For one example, just look at Microsoft's constant "re-vamping" of where to find its official documentation). That's why the question should ask for the information that solves the problem you're having, for which you want the official documentation, to be in the answer.

If the answerer should post a link to the official documentation, so much the better. If they don't, ask for it in a comment to the answer (or phrase the request very carefully in the question, itself, maybe as: "Please include a link to the official documentation, for reference").

Comment: Just as a side remark: every good answer should probably also link to the official documentation for reference.

Comment: ^^ I absolutely agree! @Trilarion

Comment: So you are saying that rather than asking "Where is the official documentation for Y  (which is a single purpose utility that does nothing but X)" I should ask "What is the officially documented way to do X using Y? Please include links to that documentation."? -- Seems like the same thing with more words. :-(

Comment: @BCS Not really, because the result *should be* that the information about the "how" will be in the Answer, on Stack Overflow, rather than in a link. This is important because the site is a Q&A for everyone and the future. It's purpose is *not* to be a help desk for individuals asking one-off questions. Since links can go bad, it's important, in the concept of the site, that all relevant information is stored here, where it (ideally) cannot be lost. It's a question of perspective - you don't (yet) regard the site the way it's been designed to be used.

Comment: Maybe in some cases, but in the case in question the correct answer is "copy the boilerplate documented `here`, wherever it happens to be at the time you read it". -- If that link goes stale, than it's likely that any cache of that boilerplate is **also** stale, and thus now also wrong.