# Why was this answer deleted when it addressed the question?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, link-only-answers

In the question [Google Analytics Metrics and Dimension Exclusion groups](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15406704/47278) the user asked if anyone can share the list of groups.  I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61240354/47278) with a link to a JSON file that has this information and almost immediately my answer was deleted by a moderator without any explanation or comment about why.

> I think this may be what you're looking for:
>
> https://developers.google.com/analytics/ga_cubes.json
>
> It was referenced in the ga-dev-tools repository

I followed the help doc and flagged it for re-opening yesterday but there was been no response.

In the "[Your answer is in another castle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)" post, it specifically says:

> There's really only one valid exception to this rule, and that's when the question is:
>
> Suggest me some tutorials where i can learn quick.

I would argue that this question falls under the exception.  The user asked:

> Can anybody share this list?

I don't see how it's possible to share the list without it being a link.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: No, it's a valuable question as it's something I needed an answer to while doing software development.

Comment: This might very well be the on-topic kind of resource question described [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/386006/7296893). It's a good, hard-to-find and official resource. The only deficiency I see is that the answer could've described the resource a bit.

Comment: I would consider that particular question as "I cannot find a specific part of the official API documentation and/or specification for this", and the answer providing the link to that missing part of the documentation/specification. I don't think this is off-topic, and neither do I think this is an "external resource" answer.

Comment: I saw a moderator sigh heavily a couple of weeks ago, despairing at everybody forgetting what SO was all about.  Reliving that moment.  Again.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your answer is basically a link-only answer, and those are discouraged on SO for reasons that you're probably already familiar with. I agree that in this case, sharing the list is valuable, and anybody who actually looks at the linked file will agree that providing a link to the file is probably a better idea than pasting the entire gigantic list into an answer.

I think your answer should be undeleted, but I also think that you should edit the answer to describe the contents of the linked file and briefly explain why including the content of the file isn't practical. You might also explain how you found the list, which will help in case the file ever moves and somebody has to fix the link.

Comment: There is no point "describing the contents" in this case. That description would just be repeating the question. It might make sense to include how that list is found. But on the other hand, he sort of did that by pointing out the ga-dev-tools repository from where it's linked.

Comment: @dialer The real point in editing the question to include more information is to make it look less like the kind of link-only answer that tends to get deleted right away. The OP could say something like *the linked JSON file contains hundreds of lines and is too large to include in an answer*. The OP's answer has been restored, but without an edit it might well be deleted again by someone else.

Comment: As a moderate user of the site, it's unfortunate that I needed to bring this up here in order to get any result.  The SO Tour page says "Ask questions, get answers, no distractions"  Well, this was a huge distraction.

I can see that a moderator probably did a fly-by, saw a link and trigger-happily hit the Delete button but from a user's POV this left me perplexed because the moderator does not have to provide a reason or suggestion for improvement.

This comment isn't directed at Caleb.  I'm just piggy backing on the answer.

Comment: @MattMcCormick Mods deal with a *huge* number of posts each day -- let's help 'em out by avoiding the patterns that we know are often problematic.

Comment: That's fair.  There should just be a more inviting process when a moderator makes a mistake.  Look at this question.  It's downvoted -5 and there were a couple comments from moderators (now deleted) that were very cliquey and patronizing.

Comment: @MattMcCormick -5 is just the net score; your post was actually downvoted (as of now) 13 times and upvoted 8. Don't take any of that, or the fact that your answer was deleted in the first place, personally. Answers to very old questions are put in a "late answers" review queue, and answers that are short or consist of little more than a link are automatically put in a "low quality" review queue; these help mods and reviewers weed out the chaff. Don't expect reviewers to visit the link in a post that looks like a link-only answer; invest an extra 60 seconds to make you'r answer's value obvious.