# Is this audit in the reopen votes queue wrong?

Tags: bug, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

The reopen votes queue asked me to review [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64899827/5366641) for reopening. I have read it, as I always do, and I have decided to leave it closed. Then - BANG:

> STOP! Look and Listen.
> This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. You didn't pass. **There are no major problems with this question.** You should click Reopen, or make minor corrections via Edit and Reopen.

**Note:** The emphasis is mine.

Well,

> I am wondering which installation should I choose.

and

> Is there any installer for ARM Macs?

seem like a major problem to me, because the question asks about a *recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more*.

Comment: The question has a suboptimal wording. But they don't really ask where they can download the installer, but whether Node.js is compatible with Mac ARM and how to install it there (if no such installer exists). In general, questions about installing a programming tool are on-topic.

Comment: _I am wondering which installation should I choose._ is a straight forward asking for recommendation. It is not on-topic.

Comment: recommendations in itself are not off-topic. It is only off-topic when it's opinion based or when it asks for a off-site resource. The questions should still be edited to make it less easy to interpret it as a off-site resource search and more of a "How to install Node.js on Mac ARM".

Comment: @BDL, any installer _is_ an off-site resource.

Comment: I now edited the question with what I think op should have asked. Hope it makes it clear now that the point is not finding a download link for an installer but a fundamental problem that there exists (or existed) no installation for that specific hardware.

Comment: @BDL Does this make my decision to leave the original closed wrong?

Comment: Not sure. I, at least, wouldn't leave a question closed that I can edit into shape in 30 seconds just because of a suboptimal formulation.

Comment: See [When is a resource request on-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/386006/7296893). There's a special example for links to official resources, and I think this qualifies

Comment: @ErikA, _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other **off-site resource are off-topic** for Stack Overflow ..._ I am not a lawyer and my job is not to reinterpret texts in a search for backdoors. I am an engineer and for me the part of the definition I have marked in bold is clear enough. As long as this text stays in this form, there should not be any exceptions. If the rules change, the texts should be changed as well. There should not be any assumptions, nor interpretations.

Comment: @scopchanov The answer there is by a then-employee of Stack Overflow, they wrote the text, and are as close to the law as you can get here. If you want the text to change to incorporate this exception, you can post a feature request here, but the exception is valid, and that means the question is valid, should stay open, and the audit was legitimate.

Comment: @ErikA, I have posted a bug, because according to the current text of the flag, the question is off-topic and the audit is wrong. Whether this bug will be fixed (if at all) through updating the text, or through changing the audit's generation algorithm, is not for me to decide.

Comment: There should be a way to express disagreement with the audit decision other than opening a question in meta.  I got one today where *the question's tags had been modified inappropriately* before presenting it to me.  I voted to leave it closed for that reason (which kind of matched the fake close reason).  That's crap.

Comment: I disagree with the decision to close the post based on their perceived intention of OP. The wording of the question is suboptimal but that should not warrant closing the post. A lot of people seem to be visiting this page and could benefit from further input. I edited the post and propose to reopen it.