# Where can I ask the question: "Where can I find some documentation for ... ?"

Tags: discussion

SO is not aimed to anwser questions like "Where can I find some docs for ...?". I can understand this choice, and without doubt, the code of conduct of SO has lead to a high-quality, world-wide used platform.

But sometimes, even heavily-used technologies are lacking some important documentation. In this case, there are often some nice-quality personnal blogs, or some other helpful resources which can greatly help to solve some commons issues.

I understand that many times, newbie programmers don't take the time to search deeply for their issues. But my question is not about newbie programmers.

Sometimes, even for "skilled" programmers (at least, for me!), some needs are very specific, and some wonderful resources are not easily findable. I often need anwsers to questions like "Where can I find some documentation about a specific problem ?", but I don't know **where** to ask these questions.

Where can I ask this kind of questions ? Indeed, SO forbids it. Is there another StackExchange site where these questions are welcome?

**EDIT**

I will read carefully the links given by the nice people who answered to me, but I can "answer" the question for now, thank you all.

Comment: You can't. That's _off-topic_ on almost all SE network sites IIAIC.

Comment: Why? What is the problem with this? Could you share me some SE links where such things are explained or discussed, please?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153220/why-is-asking-for-references-sources-to-study-specific-topics-considered-not-con

Comment: And, well https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203147/a-question-requesting-for-official-api-documentation-url-counts-as-off-topic/203153

Comment: I think @πάνταῥεῖ missed [When is a resource request on-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385479/when-is-a-resource-request-on-topic)

Answer (score 5):

While I don't have a specific off-site resource or alternate Stack Exchange site to point you to, I do have an alternative take here.

You state (emphasis mine):

> Sometimes, even for "skilled" programmers (at least, for me!), some needs are **very specific**, and some wonderful resources are not easily findable. I often need answers to questions like "Where can I find some documentation about **a specific problem**?", but I don't know where to ask these questions.

Documentation is incredibly helpful, especially when one has *many* questions, or needs an overview of a given technology/ API/ library/ etc.

That said, don't forget or underestimate the fact that Stack Overflow is exactly the *right* place to ask questions about *very specific problems*!

If you have a specific problem with some technology that's on-topic for SO, then there is definitely a way to phrase a post such that it isn't a quest for recommendations, and instead focuses on the specific problem at-hand. Don't be afraid to actually ask, *especially* when you can't find good documentation on it elsewhere.

After all, SO is designed to *become* a source of documentation for programming topics in of itself, even if it won't always supplant actual documentation when available.

---

This sentiment largely comes from reading through the answers to the post shared by [@Scratte](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/12695027/scratte), "[When is a resource request on-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385479/when-is-a-resource-request-on-topic)," which is worth taking a read through to understand (in part) why recommendation Q's are outlawed on SO.

The answers to that post make a good argument that documentation questions can be asked in such a way as not to solicit opinions, and thus avoid the associated closure, but that may be its own can of worms.

Answer (score 3):

Nowhere. Usually, you have a flag in needs improvement -> A community-specific reason -> Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more

with an explanation, "This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers."

That's pretty obvious because they are likely to attract answers like "I think this guide is the best for solving this problem! ", and it's true on all sites. There's no site whatsoever on SE that allows that.

Comment: I've heard this argument for years on SE, I can understand it. But I can also remember some times when people were trying to help me, giving me some awesome links at the moment, then closed by SE admins. Opinion-based answers couldn't be upvoted or downvoted, as well as other answers?? I can guess your answer. But it is a very frustrating problem for me, for many years, and I guess I'm not alone

Comment: @yolenoyer - Just providing links to external resources doesn’t make it an answer without any explanation, it makes it Google, we already have one of those.  Without reading the question you describe I cannot comment on the read that question was closed or the answer was deleted

Comment: @SecurityHound (still reading about the nice links everybody give) Google AI will not always give you the right links that experienced developpers will be able to give to you. I learned more from my IT friends than from google:)

Comment: @yolenoyer - Providing a link without any explanation is something Yahoo Answers would allow.  We strive for the top of the cream not the stuff at the bottom