# Is power-levelling legit in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, reputation, privileges

I came across a question titled ["Does Laravel Documentation exists?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72316132/does-laravel-documentation-exists#72316132) which surprisingly got upvotes. The question is asking about off site resources - which is off topic. It seems the people involved in the comments and answers knows each other in real life. They seem to be exchanging upvotes to gain more reputation. Is this even allowed?

[image: the question thread]

Further comments:

[image: additional comments]

I had my fair share of downvotes on valid questions (and pretty quickly at that). I also had seen many clueless people downvoted without any comments to guide them. Even better, that question edited by 22k person. It just seems kind of iffy.

Comment: **waiting for people complaining about posting images**, ok, before you shot your downvotes, that link can die any time - i just wanted to provide proof.

Comment: Votes are for _content_, not _users_, so that is misuse.

Comment: I will admit, there is a smell to those posts. The answers are of low quality, that are link only and should be flagged, but if you smell foul play then you should raise a custom mod flag. I, personally, smell a voting ring, which is against the rules.

Comment: It might come as a surprise, @BagusTesa, but we actually like images on meta. People only don't like images of *code* on main.

Comment: Please flag it for mod attention.

Comment: Btw, please don't engage in discussions of votes under users' posts - voting fraud is investigated by moderators - just flag and move on, nothing productive comes out of such engagements.

Comment: Also please, do not put emphasis on users. That only serves to call for pitchforks - this information should also go into a custom moderator flag.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine, noted. i just wanted to clarify stuff before things gone.

Comment: Thank you for bringing this to our attention. There's definitely some suspicious behavior going on here, on multiple levels. Moderators are looking into it. While we do so, I've gone ahead and locked the comments on this post, as they were rapidly getting unconstructive. In the future, as noted in comments and the linked duplicates, it's best to just bring things like this to moderators' attention via a flag on the post. You can provide all the same details in that flag that you did here. Only mods can deal with this stuff, so there's no need to bring it to Meta. Thanks!

Comment: But I just bought a new pitchfork! Man, I never get to have fun!

Comment: No one's going to call out the fact that the OP formatted Laravel as code? That only bothers me? Oh well..

Comment: One problem at a time, @HereticMonkey...

Comment: What do you mean by *"power-levelling"*? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @HereticMonkey, it was the reason i asked here. its very weird given a pure html then asking for laravel documentation (off-site resource) - with upvotes to boot, even the answer has upvotes too. i checked the user as curiousity, turns out within 40min he managed to get 3 low quality questions with upvotes.

Comment: @PeterMortensen as in new user, getting exp (rep points) "helped" by experienced user(s) to reach higher privileges as fast as possible.

Comment: While these posts do seem suspicious a bit to me, considering how quickly the answers were upvoted which are not very good, my understanding is that requests for *canonical* resources, such as official documentation, are considered on topic. For example, asking for MSDN documentation for a feature of PowerShell Core would be on topic, asking for a blog post or article detailing how to resolve the double hop problem with `Invoke-Command` would not be.

Comment: This particular question definitely smells like a voting ring, but note that [requests for *official* resources are on-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385479/when-is-a-resource-request-on-topic).

Comment: The canonical for explaining downvotes is *[Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135)*.