# Is "prefer no external libraries solutions" a hint of library recommendations?

Tags: discussion

For example, I want to solve something, preferred a solution without external libraries or frameworks, but I don't know if it is possible to solve it without external libraries, and don't want to totally refuse "use this framework" like answers. Is it ok to say "prefer no external libraries solutions" in my question? Is "prefer no external libraries solutions" read as "prefer no external libraries solutions but still allowed" and hence become a hint of library recommendations?

eg: question like above but currently closed:

[Download, read an external file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61986646/download-read-an-external-file)

currently not closed:

[What is the most efficient way to round a float value to the nearest integer in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091014/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-round-a-float-value-to-the-nearest-integer-in)

Comment: Yes, it should be okay to say "prefer no external libraries solutions". The first example you show shouldn't have been closed due to that reason (Duplicate closure would have been suitable). The second example is also fine.

Comment: Qt DV'ed for not mentioning "your" Prog-Lang and I didn't want to click-bait on the 2 Links, "*but I don't know if it is possible to solve it without external libraries*", => afaik it's **always** *possible* to "*solve it* without External Libraries... External Libraries [can] only use what's already available for Func in the "main" Repository/Compiler/Runtime_Engine... [Sbd prove me wrong maybe, (with Ref and Proof), ... and I will shut my big mouth, ah-ah...!]

Comment: Yep, 15min later, still thinking "if I was right", 'JS' (JavaScript) that I know "best", has complete access to the OS (from a Browser), the Syntax is a bit "obscure", but you can completely wipe a C Drive, I "suspect" that's also possible from all other "major" Prog-Langs...

Comment: Yep, 3 Lines in pure 'JS', (to wipe a C Drive), (not "completely" tested, well..., I quite like my Laptop, ah-ah...!, but I'm pretty sure it would work, with no Prompt whatever...)...

Comment: @chivracq I don't know what you're getting at, but downvoting this question because it doesn't mention a programming language indicates that you should perhaps refrain from voting. The question is _"Is it ok to say "prefer no external libraries solutions" in my question?"_, which is not specific to any language at all. Also, if you think you have three lines of JavaScript that can wipe a C drive through the browser, pleases report it to the browser maker, because that would be a massive vulnerability.

Comment: Where it becomes a grey area for me is how seriously answerers should take that restriction since it is a highly personalised wish without a really clear reasoning and questions are asked to aid the many, not the one. So would an answer that does suggest a library which is absolutely perfect for the job be a "bad" answer?

Comment: @CodeCaster, well, "*in my question*" will be specific to *that question* and therefore to a specific Prog-Lang, and the Answer (to this current Qt on 'Meta') could be different for different Prog-Langs... // Hum, the Technique/"Vulnerability" I have in mind can be applied to all Browsers, and (variations of) it seem(s) to already be documented, [here](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/30285) already in some CVE from 2007 (applied to 'FF' + 'IE' + 'Netscape'(!), no Versions mentioned). [1/2]...

Comment: --- [2/2] And also in several Threads on 'SO', [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53590840) + [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6477875/3799241) for example, and also in [several Threads](https://forum.imacros.net/search.php?st=0&sk=t&sd=d&sr=posts&keywords=initWithPath) on the Forum for the small Tag I follow/answer on 'SO'... Hum, and can be done in just 1 Line apparently...

Comment: @chivracq https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-NKOIuc1n34g/UNVvLLVtGwI/AAAAAAAABaE/Uz5uaPwIdOY/s1600/Unique+Fork.jpg

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is a resource request on-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385479/when-is-a-resource-request-on-topic) TL;DR just edit it to be a question about how to solve a specific problem.

Answer (score 23):

No, it's really the opposite. "Is there a library to do X" questions are off-topic not because we dislike libraries, but because such questions tend to be magnets for off-topic and opinion-based answers as well as illicit promotion of tangentially related software.

Quite distinctly, "How can I do X?" is a question which could and should sometimes be answered by "Use library Y"; but of course, separately mentioning that you would prefer to avoid a third-party dependency is fine, and if anything, is the *opposite* of requesting a library.

(Separately, questions asking merely "How can I do X?" tend to be badly received for other reasons. Show us your research and demonstrate a basic understanding of the problem domain so that we can zoom in on the detail you are having trouble with. See also [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))