# How should I flag a clearly off-topic question?

Tags: support, flags

The question is: [Why people of India faced poverty in large numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77998667/why-people-of-india-faced-poverty-in-large-numbers) (it's deleted now).

It is clearly off-topic, but there isn't any "off-topic" flag. How should I flag it?

Comment: "Needs improvement" > "A community-specific reason" > "Not about programming or software development"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts

Comment: Relevant: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426811/needs-improvement-flag

Comment: Relevant, but outdated and thus not helpful here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257883/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Other than the [flag reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) visible at first glance when clicking the flag button, clicking on the "**Needs improvement**" option allows you to flag corresponding to a [closure reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417476/question-close-reasons-definitions-and-guidance).

In case a question isn't [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) you should use the [not about programming or software development](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417476/question-close-reasons-definitions-and-guidance/420218#420218) reason.

So in this case you should select: "Needs improvement" > "A community-specific reason" > "Not about programming or software development"