Why was my question closed for seeking recommendations?
I posted a question: Which warnings has to be explicitly defined for MSVC [closed] which got closed for "seeking recommendations".
Can someone please explain where I seek a suggestion about a software?

Not on Stack Overflow.

"How do I force people to read the questions I post" -- Why should a volunteer be forced to do anything? I'm sorry, but your request is quite presumptive and, to be honest, shows a significant degree of entitlement.

@HovercraftFullOfEels, I'm just curious - how to make people read the question before closing it? Because the question is legitimate as far as I'm concern. And the title here is rhetorical. More over you read both the question and the bod of the post before answering, right? So why not everybody doing so? Because I don't think the closing was done without reading the full question.

@Igor - You asked for documentation. Asking for documentation is a close reason. I concluded this within 15 seconds and reading the single sentence in the original revision of the linked question. Here is that close reason. Editing your question to say, I am not actually asking for a documentation recommendation, does not change the fact you actually are asking for documentation not found on Stack Overflow. This question is borderline offensive in that your seeking ways to force other users to read your question assuming they have not already done so.

"how to make people read the question before closing it? Because the question is legitimate as far as I'm concern." You are not the one who gets to decide if the question is legitimate. People did read it. They decided it is not legitimate. According to our rules. We get to set those, because there is already a community that those rules protect. The rules are there so the community can serve its purpose. Not yours.

@KarlKnechtel, then n question can be answered with absolute certainty. Because guess what? Some answer requires citations from the standards (C++ one to be exact)). And it is off-site resource. The other requires the verification by Java documentation The other has to have a reference t the external site because people are downloading right package from wrong website. However I don't see those to be closed. They are all still are legitimate questions. So whether someone like it or not - this is all opinion based.

@Igor There is a difference between citing an outside source to support your answer and that outside source being your answer. You are asking for "a page somewhere in MSDN." That is an explicit request for off-site resources, which is explicitly off-topic. "No requests for off-site resources" is an established rule.

@AndrewYim, the argument still stands though - the link can go away at any time which render the answer useless, So what is the difference again? And by useless I mean "every answer should be supported by official documentation. On top of that - what about the answers that tells you that download link is wrong and you need to go to the official site for downloading. It is still off-topic, right? Or not?

@Igor if you cite documentation and the documentation changes, your answer is still valuable because there was content besides the documentation.

@AndrewYim no. asking for where to find an official resource is not off-topic. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417732/11107541

@starball Okay that's fair.

Just ask what you want to know. You don't want a link to MSDN... you want to know what said hypothetical page would say. To get that kind of information, you ask about the problem. If there is an MSDN page which would describe what you want to know, surely someone will post a link to it.

The close message states

This question is seeking recommendations for software libraries, tutorials, tools, books, or other off-site resources.

The sentence

Is there a page somewhere in MSDN which gives the list of warnings that needs to be turned on explicitly in order to be seen?

makes it pretty obvious that you are looking for a link to some external website. The same information had already been posting in a comment under your question an hour before you wrote this question.

@BIDL, could you please explain what is off-site resources are? Is MSDN one of them? What about Apple documentation? Those are official  platform resources that are referenced everywhere. Or maybe it is everything that is not on SO?

@Igor: Off-Site resource means anything that is not on SO.

which means I can't ask for documentation references, right? Because the presumption is - I can go and check the documentation myself?

@Igor: Yes, it means you can't asks for documentation references. They can be added to support an answer, but the core of the answer has to be on SO. The main reason is that links to other sites might change or die at some point and then the Q&A is useless.

Actually there is some debate on this topic where some people think questions asking for official sources are fine. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385479/when-is-a-resource-request-on-topic

Also related (and without a consensus): "Should questions about official documentation be on-topic?".

@chivracq, Now we are getting somewhere... ;-) This is an official documentation. It is always on and if something becomes deprecated - it will not disappear, ut will be marked as such and kept. Especially since it is official and it is official.

@Igor: Given that Microsoft has changed the links to their documentation at least twice, official doesn't mean that it is still reachable with the same address.

@BDL, first time I hear about that.  But its not surprising that MS screwing people up. Anyway I think I understand. Thx.

The fact that you still refer to it as "MSDN", which it hasn't been since around 2014, suggests that if you didn't know you've not been on the Microsoft's documentation site for some time then, @Igor . It changed from MSDN to Docs to Learn.

@ThomA, yes I don't go there too often. Thx for pointing that out.

@ThomA But nobody calls it that IMX... it's still "MSDN" for everyone I communicate with about it.
