"No migration allowed after 60 days so we delete instead" policy
It was requested that migration of questions to other StackExchange sites be forbidden after 60 days due to some issues it causes with regard to points/reputation, and it appears that this was then implemented (e.g.). Deletion, on the other hand, remains possible past the 60-day limit.
I didn't know either of this, so I flagged an older question for migration from StackOverflow to SoftwareRecs, only to find later that it was deleted entirely, despite having some useful comments (maybe answers too, I don't remember and now I can't check anymore).
This seems like the most user-hostile way to handle this. I would've expected that, if migration is not possible, it just gets the closed-as-off-topic banner and that's it. Is deleting such questions the actual recommended policy?

I mean... closed questions are generally destined to be deleted. The only exception is when it has an upvoted answer and remains unnoticed by people with the ability to cast delete votes who would be willing to. The sample you've provided is a bit of an edge case. If you wanted to discuss it specifically... that'd probably be best done on MSO

Well… that sucks. I have forever wanted real deletion to be reserved for content actually harmful (or very new so minimal effort has been spent on it yet), and preferred closure+locking+delisting instead for handling older content. Unfortunately, that’s not where the community has landed.

@JeremyBanks "Harmful" is of course tricky to evaluate. Some massively popular closed questions on SO contain answers that are better than nothing but have significant flaws. Their existence on the internet can push better content further down search results; are they thus harmful? I dunno; it's a very difficult case-by-case call to make. (Personally I wish we had a grandfather clause system to keep such questions open, despite them deserving closure & deletion per the rules, with a notice like the historical lock notice, so they could be maintained and better answers be posted to them.)

@MarkAmery maybe it’s a strong word, and the argument is over, but my argument traditionally would be that I’d prefer to keep them accessible with a direct link even if we mark them for exclusion from search engines and most listings on the site (except for users favorites/saves/activity).

@JeremyBanks I don't know that we have a "delisting" option? And a lot of older off-topic stuff has a lot of upvotes.

"... only to find later that it was deleted entirely, despite having some useful comments ..." - The referenced question has been deleted by the mod. 4 comments and the single 1-scored answer for over 8 years doesn't look as a reason to not delete a definitely off-topic question. High score (32) of the question itself doesn't mean much in case of off-topic questions. I just wander why the question hasn't been closed many years ago. According to timeline, it survives 3 closing attempts.

@Tsyvarev - The community isn’t perfect it can’t catch every out of scope question, after an out of scope question isn’t immediately handled the chances of it remaining increase. Ironically the raise of GenAI content (which of course isn’t allowed) results in older questions without an answer to receive attention after years of not being handled.

@KarlKnechtel We have something similar to that in the form of the infrequently-used historical lock (although it doesn’t remove them from Google), but I was originally requesting it as a more default option.

For the information of the author (and anyone else who cares), the linked question received one answer with one upvote.

@dharman, could this question have not easily been edited to be on topic? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/386006/11107541
