# Question asking for documentation location closed as "looking for books, tools, software libraries" recommendations

Tags: support, specific-question, close-reasons, reopen-closed

This question was inappropriately closed on the false basis of "asking for software recommendations" when it was about asking for technical documentation:

[Official documentation with the LIST of Microsoft Word XML namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64740687/official-documentation-with-the-list-of-microsoft-word-xml-namespaces)

Comment: You're asking for an off-site resource. That close reason is also used in that context.

Comment: *We don’t allow questions seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more* <-- did you consider the *more*?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are questions asking for documentation off-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310983/are-questions-asking-for-documentation-off-topic)

Comment: Side note: linked question asks about "XML namespaces" but showing something that is not XML nor XML namespaces...

Answer (score 4):

The close reason text says:

> We don’t allow questions seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, **and more.**

The problem with this kind of question is that it invites low-quality, link-only answers, opinions, and spam.

Comment: To be fair, the close reason also says "**seeking recommendations** for...". I wouldn't qualify the location of official documentation as a recommendation. This answer also seems to conflict with Shog's answer [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/386006/479156).